# Run CucumberJS tests in Webstorm with Harmony flag?

Tags: node.js, webstorm, ecmascript-6, cucumberjs

I am just spiking to see if we can get some of the ES6 goodness into our existing codebase, and so far so good although when I went to start up our cucumber js tests from webstorm it blows up with the ES6 syntax.

So has anyone else got this working? I have tried adding `--harmony` to the CucumberJs arguments but no luck :(

Comment: The only ES6 test framework I have seen is mocha-traceur https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-traceur - apart from this transcompile the ES6 code and run the tests on the output.

Comment: My understanding was nodejs from v11 onwards had the `--harmony` flag to  just enable certain ES6 features natively, so as CucumberJS would run on top of nodejs the syntax should be acceptable